# What is the package name for editing keybindings in gnome/budgie?

Tags: apt, gnome, keyboard, 17.10, budgie

I don't know what happened, but I lost my app for editing keyboard shortcuts. It usually there when you search for "shortcut" on a freshly installed Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with Budgie as its desktop environment. So I want to install it back using `apt` but I don't know its package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is known as "Settings" and is provided by the package `gnome-control-center`

You can install it if it has gone awol via

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

You can also launch the keyboard binding section via:

```
gnome-control-center keyboard
```

You could wrap that command into a .desktop file an place in ~/.local/share/applications to ensure it appears in the menu.